# Asynctask multiple downloading fails in Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, handler

I am downloading mp3 files (using asynctask)  and updating there progress in Listview which contains progress bar and textview (which shows how much % is downloaded). It runs ok till 2% to 3% but then crashes with this exception.

This is the code:

```
             @Override
                    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                        Log.v("Progress ", Integer.toString(values[0]));
                        pbar.setProgress(values[0]);
                        tmin.setText(Integer.toString(values[0]) + "%");

                    }
```

This is the error:

```
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587): java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@40928f80 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@40b93700[Running, pool size = 128, active threads = 128, queued tasks = 10, completed tasks = 1]
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1972)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:787)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1308)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:552)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:499)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at MusicDownloader.com.MusicDownloader$CustomAdapter.getView(MusicDownloader.java:209)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1949)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1228)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1139)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10835)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:956)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:521)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10835)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10835)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10835)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10835)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10835)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:1889)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10835)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:944)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2046)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
                07-04 05:50:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is get view

```
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

                ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);                    
                TextView t1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.minsize);
                TextView t2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.filesize);
                t2.setTypeface(tf);
                t1.setTypeface(tf);

                ImageView btn = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.cancelbtn);

                BackgroundAsyncTask bat = new BackgroundAsyncTask(downloadpool.get(position), pb, t1, t2);
                if(bat.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING){
                    // My AsyncTask has not started yet
                    bat.execute();
                }                   
                if(bat.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
                    // My AsyncTask is currently doing work in doInBackground()
                }                   
                if(bat.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
                    // My AsyncTask is done and onPostExecute was called
                }



                btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) { 
                        Log.e("app", "cancelled...");
                        //bat.cancel(true);
                    }
                 });


                return row;
        }
```

Comment: What does this line do? `MusicDownloader$CustomAdapter.getView(MusicDownloader.java:209)
`

Comment: it actually execute the asynctask

Comment: Post your code of getView() method.

Comment: its crashing at bat.execute();

Comment: can anyone plz help me out...or throw any hint